# c++ including <complex> causes a syntax error in file string

Tags: string, visual-studio-2010, syntax, complex-numbers

> Error 3   error C2059: syntax error : ')' c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\string 758 1   ECE572_001_Project1_swirl
>   Error   6   error C2059: syntax error : ')' c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\string 767 1   ECE572_001_Project1_swirl
>   Error   1   error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before 'string' c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\string 758 1   ECE572_001_Project1_swirl
>   Error   4   error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before 'string' c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\string 767 1   ECE572_001_Project1_swirl
>   Error   2   error C2665: 'swprintf' : none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types  c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\string 758 1   ECE572_001_Project1_swirl
>   Error   5   error C2665: 'swprintf' : none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types  c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\string 767 1   ECE572_001_Project1_swirl

I don't understand this error, because it says the error is in the file string, which is a locked file provided by VS2010. Second, I'm not even using string, and third, how could including complex have anything to do with the library string?

Even though including complex causes the error in my project file, I started a whole new file to test including it, and the error didn't happen there.

```
#include "Image.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>

using namespace std;

#define Usage "makeSwirl inImg outImg coeff\n"

/*
 * arg1 is the image to transform.
 * arg2 is the swirl coefficient
 * Returns image with enhanced edges.
 */
Image swirl(const Image&, const float&);
/*
 * arg1 is the image within which the pixel to be transformed is located.
 * arg2&3&4 are the row, colum, and channel of the pixel to transform.
 * arg5 is the swirl coefficient
 * arg6&7 are the rows and cols of arg1.
 * returns transformed pixel.
 */
float onePixelSwirl(const Image&, const int&, const int&, const int&, const double&, const int&, const int&);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // Check for proper number of arguments.
    if(argc != 4)
    {
        cout << Usage;
        exit(3);
    }

    // Read in image specified by user.
    const Image IN_IMG = readImage(argv[1]);

    // Create output image with oil effect.
    Image outImg = swirl(IN_IMG, atof(argv[3]));

    // Output the image
    writeImage(outImg, argv[2]);

    // Success!
    return(0);
}

Image swirl(const Image& IN_IMG, const float& COEFF)
{
    Image outImg;

    // Allocate memory
    const int ROWS = IN_IMG.getRow();
    const int COLS = IN_IMG.getCol();
    const int CHANNELS = IN_IMG.getChannel();
    outImg.createImage(ROWS, COLS, IN_IMG.getType());

    // Perform edge effect
    for (int k = 0; k < CHANNELS; ++k)
        for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; ++i)
            for (int j = 0; j < COLS; ++j)
                outImg(i,j,k) = onePixelSwirl(IN_IMG, i, j, k, COEFF, ROWS, COLS);

    return outImg;
}

float onePixelSwirl(const Image& IN_IMG, const int& ROW, const int& COL, 
    const int& CHANNEL, const double& COEFF, const int& ROWS, const int& COLS)
{
    // define shift of origin
    //const double X_SHIFT = ROWS/2.0;
    //const double Y_SHIFT = COLS/2.0;
    //const complex<double> NEW_SHIFTED(ROW - X_SHIFT, COL - Y_SHIFT);


    //const double r = abs(NEW_SHIFTED);
    //const complex<double> OLD_SHIFTED = polar(r, arg(NEW_SHIFTED) + r/COEFF);
    //const int OLD_ROW = OLD_SHIFTED.real() <= ROWS ? OLD_SHIFTED.real() : ROWS;
    //const int OLD_COL = OLD_SHIFTED.imag() <= COLS ? OLD_SHIFTED.imag() : COLS;

    //return IN_IMG(OLD_ROW, OLD_COL, CHANNEL);
    return 0;
}
```

I put the include statement above including image.h, and the compilation bugs vanished. Here is image.h if someone could figure out the problem:

```
/********************************************************************
 * Image.h - header file of the Image library which defines 
 *           a new class "Image" and the associated member functions
 *
 * Author: Hairong Qi, hqi@utk.edu, ECE, University of Tennessee
 *
 * Created: 02/05/02
 *
 * Note: 
 *   This is a simple C++ library for image processing. 
 *   The purpose is not high performance, but to show how 
 *   the algorithm works through programming.
 *   This library can only read in PGM/PPM format images. 
 *
 * Modification:
 *   07/31/09 - moving header files for colorProcessing, imageIO, and
 *               matrixProcessing to this file
 *   01/22/06 - reorganize the Image library such that the Image class
 *              only contains member functions related to the most 
 *              fundamental image operation
 *   11/12/05 - add wavelet transform function
 *   09/26/05 - add Fourier transform related functions
 *   09/07/05 - add overloading function for "/"
 *   09/07/05 - modify createImage() function
 *   09/07/05 - fix problems with copy constructor
 *   08/07/05 - regrouping functions
 ********************************************************************/

#ifndef IMAGE_H
#define IMAGE_H

#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

#define PGMRAW   1                     // magic number is 'P5'
#define PPMRAW   2                     // magic number is 'P6'
#define PGMASCII 3                     // magic number is 'P2'
#define PPMASCII 4                     // magic number is 'P3'
#define GRAY     10                    // gray-level image
#define BINARY   11                    // binary image

#define NBIT 8         
#define L ( pow(2.0,NBIT)-1 )    // the largest intensity represented by NBIT

class Image {
  friend ostream & operator<<(ostream &, Image &);
  friend Image operator/(Image &, double);    // image divided by a scalar
  friend Image operator*(Image &, double);    // image multiplied by a scalar
  friend Image operator+(Image &, double);    // image add a scalar
  friend Image operator-(Image &, double);    // image subtract a scalar

 public:
  // constructors and destructor
  Image();                             // default constructor 
  Image(int,                           // constructor with row
        int,                           // column
        int t=PGMRAW);                 // type (use PGMRAW, PPMRAW, 
                                       // PGMASCII, PPMASCII)
  Image(const Image &);                // copy constructor 
  ~Image();                            // destructor 

  // create an image
  void createImage();                  // create an image, parameters all set
  void createImage(int,                // create an image with row
           int c=1,            // column (default 1, a column vector)
           int t=PGMRAW);      // and type, default is PGMRAW
  void initImage(float init=0.0);      // initiate the pixel value of an img
                                       // the default is 0.0

  // get and set functions
  int getRow() const;                  // get row # / the height of the img 
  int getCol() const;                  // get col # / the width of the image 
  int getChannel() const;              // get channel number of the image
  int getType() const;                 // get the image type 
  float getMaximum() const;            // get the maximum pixel value
  void getMaximum(float &,             // return the maximum pixel value
          int &, int &);       // and its indices
  float getMinimum() const;            // get the mininum pixel value
  void getMinimum(float &,             // return the minimum pixel value
          int &, int &);       // and its indices
  Image getRed() const;                // get the red channel
  Image getGreen() const;              // get the green channel
  Image getBlue() const;               // get the blue channel
  Image getImage(int) const;           // get the kth channel image, 
                                       // k starts at 0

  void setRow(int);                    // set row number 
  void setCol(int);                    // set column number 
  void setChannel(int);                // set the number of channel
  void setType(int t=PGMRAW);          // set the image type
  void setRed(Image &);                // set the red channel
  void setGreen(Image &);              // set the green channel
  void setBlue(Image &);               // set the blue channel
  void setImage(Image &, int);         // set the kth channel image,
                                       // k starts at 0

  // operator overloading functions
  float & operator()(int,                  // operator overloading (i,j,k)
             int c = 0,            // when c=k=0, a column vector 
             int k = 0) const;     
  const Image operator=(const Image &);    // = operator overloading
  Image operator+(const Image &) const;    // overloading + operator
  Image operator-(const Image &) const;    // overloading - operator
  Image operator*(const Image &) const;    // overloading pixelwise *
  Image operator/(const Image &) const;    // overloading pixelwise division
  Image operator->*(const Image &) const;  // overloading ->* operator 
                                           // (matrix multiplication) 

  bool IsEmpty() const { return (image==NULL); }

 private:
  int row;                  // number of rows / height 
  int col;                  // number of columns / width 
  int channel;              // nr of channels (1 for gray, 3 for color)
  int type;                 // image type (PGM, PPM, etc.)
  int maximum;              // the maximum pixel value
  float *image;             // image buffer
};


////////////////////////////////////
// image I/O
Image readImage(char *);             // read image
void writeImage(Image &,             // write an image
                char *,
                int flag=0);         // flag for rescale, rescale when == 1
Image rescale(Image &,               // rescale an image
              float a=0.0,           // lower bound
              float b=L);            // upper bound


////////////////////////////////////
// color processing routines
Image RGB2HSI(Image &);              // convert from RGB to HSI model
Image HSI2RGB(Image &);              // convert from HSI to RGB model


////////////////////////////////////
// matrix manipulation
Image transpose(Image &);            // image transpose
Image inverse(Image &);              // image inverse
Image pinv(Image &);                 // image pseudo-inverse
Image subImage(Image &,              // crop an image
               int,                  // starting row index
               int,                  // starting column index
               int,                  // ending row index
               int);                 // ending column index


#endif
```

Comment: If the error doesn't occur in a fresh project, the error is somehow related to your code - therefore, showing your code (or even better, a cut-down minimal snippet that still has the problem) would help.

Comment: There's a syntax error in something before your `#include<complex>` line.  Either in the file or at the end of another include file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a number of things that are suspicious but the main one is the definition of `L`.  If I recall, `L` is used to indicate a Unicode string literal as in `L"Some Unicode text"`.  It seems likely that `<complex>` uses this.  By including `Image.h` before `<complex>`, you've redefined it.  This would also explain the broken calls to `swprintf()`.

Since you don't use `L` in `Image.h` is there any reason to declare it there?  If `L` is part of the interface and actually needs to be in the header file, consider renaming it to something less likely to provoke a name conflict.

Other things that look suspicious but aren't necessarily the problem here:  You've included `<cmath>` in `Image.h` for no apparent reason.  Generally, you should only include the files you actually need.  A bigger issue is the `using namespace std` in the header.  This is almost always a bad idea since it pulls every name in the std namespace into the local scope of every file that includes this header file.  It greatly increases the chance of name collisions that could be tricky to sort out (as you can see)

Comment: It's my teacher's library, so I cannot much change it (and I also don't know enough c++ to change it very well). But I did read most of accelerated c++ and noticed the including namespace statement in the header too (as the book warns against doing that). I also noticed some functions take nonconstant references yet never change the input, so these are functions that SHOULD be perfectly fine to pass a const to it, but the way it's defined prevents it.

Comment: Also, thanks for isolating the problem. I'll probably tell her your findings, so she can improve the library for future students.